# time stamp - how to calculate time difference in seconds with a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, time, stamp

I have a pandas dataframe with id and date as the 2 columns - the date column has all the way to seconds.

```
data = {'id':[17,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18],'date':['2018-01-16','2018-01-26','2018-01-27','2018-02-11',
                                                  '2018-03-14','2018-01-28','2018-02-12','2018-02-25','2018-03-04'],
       }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to have a new column - (tslt) - 'time_since_last_transaction'.  The first transaction for each unique user_id could be a number say 1. Each subsequent transaction for that user should measure the difference between the 1st time stamp for that user and its current time stamp to generate a time difference in seconds.

I used the datetime and timedelta etc.  but did not have too much of luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `groupby().transform()`:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])

df1['diff'] = df1['date'].sub(df1.groupby('id').date.transform('min')).dt.total_seconds()
```

Output:

```
   id       date       diff
0  17 2018-01-16        0.0
1  17 2018-01-26   864000.0
2  17 2018-01-27   950400.0
3  17 2018-02-11  2246400.0
4  17 2018-03-14  4924800.0
5  18 2018-01-28        0.0
6  18 2018-02-12  1296000.0
7  18 2018-02-25  2419200.0
8  18 2018-03-04  3024000.0
```

Comment: Thanks Quang - this worked really well. Appreciate it.